# What is this angular data binding expression doing behind the scenes

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-directive

Expression Binding question:
If I have something like the following line in my directive:

```
<div ng-model="ngModel" >
    <button ng-click="signature = accept()">Sign</button>
</div>
```

directive:

```
angular.module('app.layout')
.directive('signature', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            ngModel: '='
        },
        require: 'ngModel',

        link: function ($scope, elem, attr) {
            $scope = attr.ngModel;

        },
        templateUrl: 'src/client/app/widgets/signature/signature.html'
    };
});
```

What is going on here?

```
<button ng-click="signature = accept()">Sign</button>
```

Is this the equivilant of :
A:

```
$scope.ngModel.signature  = accept();
```

B:

```
ngModel.signature  = accept();
```

C:

```
var signature  = accept();
```

D:

```
this.signature  = accept();
```

E: None of the above.

---

Does the $scope bind $scope.ngModel.signature or $scope.signature or to something else?

What happens to that `signature`?

Also is it valid or even a good idea to do

```
ng-click="signature = accept()"
```

? (Thinking no... because of lack of clarity but, maybe I'm wrong. )

---

**Update:**
Full disclosure: I'm looking at 
https://github.com/legalthings/angular-signature
and the basic example is:

```
<signature-pad accept="accept" clear="clear" height="220" width="568"></signature-pad>
<button ng-click="clear()">Clear signature</button>
<button ng-click="signature = accept()">Sign</button>
```

and I am writing signature delegate that uses it in the html template.

Comment: Your ng-click is essentially running `$scope.signature = $dvope.accept()`. It is unaffected by the `ng-model` and does not use the `signature` directive

Comment: Thank you sir~ I'd accept your answer if you put it as an answer (assuming you meant $scope.signature = $scope.accept())